# Designing Bookmark Database Table

Tags: mysql, database-design

I designed my bookmark database table and discovered the following attributes as part of my bookmark table according to my project.


1. Bookmark_id int(20) auto increment as primary key

2. Created_at Datetime Current_Timestamp

3. Project_ID int (as a foreign key)= Project ID which is going to bookmark

4. User_ID (as a foreign key)=  Includes the user id who is going to bookmark the project


Now my question is

Are these attributes are fulfilling the property of bookmark table ???

Do I need more attributes ?? if yes than what kind of attributes should be enter in this database table with what name and type ?? 

Any Suggestions???

Comment: Write the `SELECTs`; that will help you decide what you need.

Comment: @RickJames I didn't get you ??? could you elaborate your comment please

Comment: @Drew what do you mean by this ?

Comment: You asked about more attributes; Drew was suggesting some.  ;)  I was pointing out that you can't design a schema without knowing how it will be used.

Comment: @RickJames it means that all I need is to work ahead on this database. Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

This table appears to implement a many-to-many relationship between "project" and "user".

Question:  Is a "user" allowed to have more than one "bookmark" in a given "project"?

The table schema appears to support multiple bookmarks to a project, since there doesn't appear to be a unique constraint on `(user_id, project_id)`.

Question: Does a bookmark represent just a link between a project and a user, or does it also need to represent a location, or a phase, or something else within the project?

Question: Can a "bookmark" exist that is not related to a user, or is not  related to a project?

i.e. consider whether the user_id and project_id columns should allow NULL values.

It's possible that there are no other attributes needed for a "bookmark". In that case, your design would be sufficient. There's no need to add unnecessary columns to the table.

You could easily add additional attributes as they are discovered, if they are needed. Some ideas that come to mind... bookmark last used or visited (datetime), user provided comment (varchar), etc. I don't know the specification, or the problem space this application/database is designed to solve, so I'm just guessing.

Comment: it's a relationship like <b> Many users can bookmark many project IDs
For Example. There are 400 users and they bookmark same project id or bookmark different project ids. The purpose of doing this is to update the user about any changes occurs in their bookmarked project.
Question Answer:
1. Yes, it represents a link between user and project as if some modification occurs it will notify the user with the help of notifications to see what changes occur in the project.
2. No there is no as such bookmark occur which is related other than to like its favorite project.

Comment: No it doesn't happen because bookmark database is not for the regular user it is for register user and same is the case with project ID <br> what do you mean by bookmark last used is this helpful ?? if yes then under what conditions. @spencer7593

Comment: @Naveed Cheema:  I was just asking the kinds of questions we ask when we do entity relationship modeling... when we discover requirements. From the question, the entity "bookmark" isn't described... all we see in the question is what looks like is a table that resolves a many-to-many relationship. The questions I asked are the kinds of questions that need to be asked and answered. I can't answer those questions. I don't know what these entities are... I don't know what "user" represents, or "project". Now introduced are potential entities "notification", "regular user" vs "register user"

Comment: @NaveedCheema: Consider entities "committee" and "person", with a many-to-many relationship between them. We might call that relationship "membership". There might be a join_date and leave_date. There might also be a role associated membership, chairman, secretary, voting member, etc. It's possible that a many-to-many relationship is itself is an entity. But sometimes a many-to-many relationship is not an entity (person, place, thing, concept, event that can be uniquely identified, is important to the business and we can store information about.)

Comment: @NaveedCheema:  My suggestion of "last used" date was considering a "bookmark" like one in an e-book, or like in a web browser. In a web browser, we might want to keep track of the most recent usage of the "bookmark" link, the last time a user clicked on it to visit a page. Same as in an e-book reader, we might want to keep track of the last time the reader visited the page referenced by the "bookmark". Or we might not want to keep track. If we did want to keep track of that, we might want that to be an attribute on the "bookmark".

Comment: ok so you want me to create a current timestamp attribute named last visited on the basis of which I'll sort the list of bookmarks. Am I right ?

Comment: @NaveedCheema:  It was just a suggestion. An example of an attribute that might be applicable to the "bookmark" entity.  Do you need to add an attribute? Not necessarily. Only add attributes that you need.